# Compute user defined function output by group in R

Tags: r, apply, tapply

I am trying to calculate z-statistic over regular interval of rows.

```html
mean = 77
std = 31
samp.45 = rnorm(45,mean,std)

z.test = function(a, mu, sd){
zeta = (mean(a) - mu) / (sd / sqrt(length(a)))
return(zeta)
}

z.hypothesis =  function(a, mu, sd){
z.stat = z.test(a,mu,sd)
if(abs(z.stat)>1.96){
return(1)
}
else{
return(0)
 }
}

group = as.numeric(ceiling(1:45/15))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(samp.45, group))
## Correct this
tapply(df$samp.45, as.factor(df$group), z.hypothesis(df$samp.45,mean,std))
```

I was planning to use *tapply* to perform function calculation for each group and return the output. I know that simple functions like *mean* can be applied directly and give the desired result, but how can I get a similar output for my own function? Any other approach is also welcome.

```html
> tapply(df$samp.45, as.factor(df$group), mean)
       1        2        3 
78.19556 79.65747 68.91818
```

Comment: `tapply(df$samp.45, as.factor(df$group), function(x) z.hypothesis(x,mean,std)) `

Comment: @pieca why don't you write it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapply(df$samp.45, as.factor(df$group), function(x) z.hypothesis(x,mean,std))`

Comment: That's it?! :P Well, I thought about it, then felt maybe since the function is already defined it would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In the `tidyverse` you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(zh=z.hypothesis(samp.45, MEAN, std))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  group    zh
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     2     0
3     3     0
```

Avoid to use internal function names as variable names. Thus I renamed `mean` to `MEAN`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is also a neat solution.